# App is crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access

i setted `NSString *oldChat` in the header file like this:

```
@interface CTFChatViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString *oldChat;
}
- (void)updateChat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *oldChat;

@end
```

and then i used it:

```
- (void)updateChat
{
    NSString *chat = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://theshay.byethost7.com/chat.php"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    if (![chat isEqual:oldChat]) 
    {
        [webView loadHTMLString:chat baseURL:nil];
        oldChat = chat;
    }

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateChat) withObject:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    NSString *chat = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://theshay.byethost7.com/chat.php"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    oldChat = chat;
    [webView loadHTMLString:chat baseURL:nil];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateChat) withObject:nil];
}
```

App crashed on `if (![chat isEqual:oldChat])` with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.
why it crashed ?

(XCode 4.5.2, iPhone Simulator 6.0, Base SDK 6.0)

Comment: why are you making property of oldChat, if you are not going to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oldChat is `autorelease` object. Retain it and use  isEqualToString for string comparison.

```
 NSString *chat = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://theshay.byethost7.com/chat.php"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
 oldChat = chat;
[oldChat retain];
```

Comment: do not forget to release oldChat in dealloc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your NSString is equal or not using isEqualToString: method. Your code should be like this

```
if (![chat isEqualToString:oldChat]){
    //Do something
}
```